# Docker with dotnet restore causes error: GSSAPI operation failed - An unsupported mechanism was requested

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-2.2

Having an ASP.NET Core 2.2 web application, I try to restore NuGet packages behind a coperate proxy

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS sdk-image
WORKDIR /app/
ARG HTTP_PROXY
ENV HTTP_PROXY ${HTTP_PROXY}
ENV HTTPS_PROXY ${HTTP_PROXY}
COPY MyProject.csproj .

RUN dotnet restore
```

with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  tool:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        http_proxy: ${HTTP_PROXY}
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.239.0/21
```

The network got overriden because Dockers default network conflicts with internal company ranges. `HTTP_PROXY` is set on the host to a full url like `http://user:password@proxy.internal:81`.

When running `docker-compose up --build` it fails on restore:

```
Step 7/15 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in 62c8bb6f2f72
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.402/NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/app/MyProject.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.402/NuGet.targets(123,5): error :   GSSAPI operation failed with error - An unsupported mechanism was requested (Unknown error). [/app/MyProject.csproj]
ERROR: Service 'tool' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I could not find much information about this issue. [A Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/34369) got this through their local TFS. But I don't have any self hosted repository, just the corporate proxy between me and NuGets server.

Comment: GSSAPI is related to Kerberos authentication, which is used by Active Directory. It seems that your corporate proxy is getting in the way. You should ask your IT team about the proxy and why it would be trying to force Kerberos auth like this.

Answer (score 11):

Seems like this is caused when the proxy requires NTLM, but the corresponding library is missing. I had this problem behind a corporate proxy and fixed it by installing the `gss-ntlmssp` package like this in Docker:

```
RUN apt-get install -y gss-ntlmssp
```

After installing those package, the authentication to the proxy for fetching NuGet packages works well.

Comment: Thank you so much. It saves my day!

Comment: Thank you Lion ! You saved me